# How to disable Wp-PageNavi at the top of the page

Tags: plugins, pagination, customization

By default, the Wp-PageNavi plugin creates 2 pagination links, from the second page onwards - one at the top, and another at the bottom of the page. How can I disable the pagination at the top, keeping only the pagination at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your theme.

If you can paste the code of the page in question, i can tell you which part to remove.

if you found something like `<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>`
make sure to remove it

have a backup first ;)

Comment: I am using a child theme with Thematic. Is it doable from a functions.php ?

Comment: are you familiar with firebug ? maybe if u can paste the code of that page in some pastebin i will be able to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin settings, but likely it is theme that has call to plugin's function in template or adds it to hook.

Look for `wp_pagenavi()` call in template or `add_action` with it in `functions.php`.